# angular ng-repeat inside modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-modal

I have a link which on clicking opens a modal. Am using angular ui modal. Inside modal I have a row with two inputs and an Add button. On clicking Add button, a new row is added with the text I entered in inputs. I have a done button which closes the modal. On opening the modal again, my newly added row is missing.

Comment: show us some code please

Comment: that probably because the modal is opened by a function like 

new modal();

try to find the function to reopen it

Comment: That's because you are not saving your new array on the modal callback. When you close the modal, pass as parameter the new array, and in the controller which opens the modal, in the .then(), save to the scope the new array

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you create a new Modal, you'll be running the code behind it again, effectively erasing any changes you make to it, even if you are using the same controller as the page you create the modal from.

To do what you want to do, you'll have to;

```
var modal= $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: ''
            }
        });
modal.result.then(function(array){
    $scope.rowArray = array
}
```

Your modal close function will then be;

```
$uibModalInstance.close($scope.rowArray);
```

This example will work if you're using the same controller for the modal and main HTML page, otherwise you'll need to have a resolve for your $uibModal.open to pass it through to the modal controller, but also add your rowArray to the dependencies of that controller.

Hope it helps!

Comment: try adding code snipet of working example ! that would make things clear.May be an up vote for that !